# Does QPointer::clear() delete its referenced pointer, or does "Clears this QPointer object." mean something else?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, heap-memory, qpointer

`QPointer` has a method, [`clear()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html#clear).

> Clears this QPointer object.

I am not sure what "clear" exactly means. In my mind, it could mean

1. It deletes the pointer you referenced.

or

2. It un-attaches the pointer you referenced, leaving that pointer on the heap, and the `QPointer<T>` object no longer tied to any pointer.

Maybe it means something else? Could you please let me know what it actually does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QPointer` is a tracking pointer. It tracks the lifetime of an object. It doesn't do any owning duties. It never will deallocate any storage owned by `QObject`. It can deallocate the underlying implementation detail - the shared reference object, but that doesn't affect anything really that the user cares about; those objects are deallocated only when the underlying `QObject` is gone and the last `QPointer` is being destructed.

> It deletes the pointer you referenced.

That's IMHO a rather confusing language. Pointers are values. To *reference a pointer* has a well established meaning:

```
const int *q = ....; // a pointer
*q; // a pointer dereference (not used for anything)
```

To me, "deleting a pointer" is this:

```
// dynamically allocate a pointer
int **p = new int*();
// make it point somewhere
int i = {};
assert(0 == i);
*p = &i;
// use it
**p = 44;
assert(44 == i);
// delete it
delete p; // a pointer-to-integer got deleted
```

> It un-attaches the pointer you referenced, leaving that pointer on the heap, and the `QPointer<T>` object no longer tied to any pointer.

It's pointers galore for sure, but that's veritable goobledygook. Just because I might understand what you mean doesn't imply that anyone should talk that way :)

A `QPointer<T>` tracks the lifetime of a `T`-instance, an **object**. It's **objects** it tracks, not pointers. So `clear()` makes the `QPointer` not track whatever object of type `T` it was tracking. That's all. And that's how to say it without making everyone doubt their sanity :)

It is true that the way you *make* a `QPointer` *track* an object is by pointing to it via a raw pointer. That's just how you get a `QPointer` going, that's all.

It is incorrect to conflate `QPointer` with heap - no heap is involved in the example below, at least not explicitly. The `obj` instance is an automatic variable. Implementations are free to put it on the dynamic store of some kind - even a literal heap, but that's typical of C++ interpreters and not what we're usually used to :)

```
#include <QtCore>
int main() {
  QPointer<QObject> p;
  Q_ASSERT(p.isNull());
  {
    QObject obj;
    p = &obj;
    Q_ASSERT(!p.isNull());
  }
  Q_ASSERT(p.isNull());
}
```